# Load balancer on Bind level with websocket support?

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, load-balancing, scalability

I am trying to finally solve the problem of the best, most effective, *possibly* low-cost way to scale a huge NodeJS/MongoDB, real-time, modern app, using Nginx. I do not have such app, it is strictly theoretical: I think it is good to learn and to do it the correct way since the very beginning, so it is easy to scale in case of growing in a future.

Below is a schema of my "contemplations" of what I managed to figure out. I was trying to take into account the most important aspects of such infrastructure, yet not including the application itself (optimizating mongoDB queries etc.). I assume the application is universal, so it might fit Facebook-like-social-network or IMDB-like-app as well.

The idea is, all You have to do - in order to effective scale - is to simply add more servers of a proper type. The schema goes like this (for a high res img, [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AagF6.png)):

[image: The infrastructure schema]

**My question is**, how to add few more (P)roxy servers, so in case of being offline, this machine has some working substitutes? In other words, is it possible to add some few more records A in Bind, and make it somehow supporting websockets, the similar way Nginx IP_HASH directive within upstream section does? It would be perfect to use a load balancer (supporting Websockets) on Bind level to enhance all the app.

Bind9 uses round-rubin to serve proper A record (if many), but it is defined to be ciclic.

```
;; A records section
proxy1  IN  A  192.168.1.1
proxy2  IN  A  192.168.1.2
proxy3  IN  A  192.168.1.3
proxy4  IN  A  192.168.1.4
```

How to handle websockets with many A records servers (using nginx as a proxy servers)?

Cheers!

Mike